# How to update meta tags using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I had tried using

```
$('meta[name=description]').attr('content', 'new value');
```

But the above is not working in any browser.

Please suggest

Comment: What does "not working" mean? In which browsers?

Comment: It works for me, why do you think it isn't working? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: What is the point of updating a meta description tag with javascript?  These types of meta tags are usually for crawlers and the crawlers won't see what the JS changes anyway because they generally don't execute JS.

Comment: "Not working" is _never_ a sufficient problem description.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems fine to me.

```
$(function () { // dom ready
    var $meta = $('meta[name=description]').attr('content', 'hi');
    $('body').text($meta.attr('content'));​
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/F7GbX/

You are probably not checking when the dom is ready.  Therefore meta tags aren't available yet.

When an html page is rendered, all the tags you write such as `<meta>` might be loaded AFTER your javascript is ready. Therefore, you must run your code inside the `domready` call so that the code isn't run until all the tags in the page have been loaded.

Under the hood of jQuery - this method uses `DOMContentLoaded`.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DOM_event_reference/DOMContentLoaded

Answer (score 4):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
    $('meta[name=description]').attr('content', 'new value');
})
```

Comment: or `$(document).ready(function() {});`

Comment: still not working i tried the above code also..

Comment: @MATT if you post some more codes, I can help you.

Comment: <html>
<head>
  <meta name="description" content="NEED_TO_UPDATE_THIS" />
<meta name="keywords" content="this" />

  <style>p { color:red; }</style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
 
     $("p").text("The DOM is now loaded and can be manipulated.");
     
   var $meta = $('meta[name=description]').attr('content', 'hi');
    $('div').text($meta.attr('content'));
  
});
  </script>

</head>
<body>
  <p>Not loaded yet.</p>
<div></div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: i want to update meta description contents on  jquery call

Comment: lol @MATT update your question with this HTML..

Comment: @gabriel could you please provide a solution as there is some problem from my edit question side ....:)

Comment: No probs it was my .net cache having rendering problem it's solved

Comment: If my answer solved your ploblem, please, select as accepted.